# Jquery Binding value to textbox based on user input to other textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 textboxes:

```
<table id="table1">
  <tr id="first_row">
    <td><input type="text" id="txt1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txt2"><td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I have it so that one's text is populated by the content of another:

```
$('#txt2').keyup(function(){
  var content = $('#txt2').val();
  $('#txt1').val(content);
});
```

And when #txt2's content is empty, I am trying to get #txt1's content to have the string "empty".

Something like:

```
if ($('#txt2').val('')) {
  $('#txt1').val('empty');
}
```

but in real time, as opposed to just on the page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `placeholder` attribute. When the input has an empty string as it's value, browser shows the specified placeholder.

If that's not option and you want to handle it using JavaScript:

```
$('#txt2').keyup(function(){
  var content = this.value.trim() || "empty";
  $('#txt1').val(content);
}).triggerHandler('keyup');
```

Also note that for comparison you should code:

```
if ( $('#txt2').val() === '' ) {
   // value is an empty string
}
```

`$('#txt2').val('')` sets the value of the `input`  and returns a jQuery object and an object is considered a truthy value in JavaScript.